# How can i change center of rotation in css?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dafter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <hr style=" margine: 20px; transform: rotatz(20deg);>
</body>
</html>
```

> This code is to rotate line
> How can i change center of rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform-origin`. Some examples.

```
transform-origin: center;
transform-origin: top left;
transform-origin: 100px 100px;
```